# Where i did mistake in this first Zend Framework 2 program

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

First create a folder coinsproject then,
coinsproject-->config folder,src folder,view folder,autoload_classmap.php,Module.php

In Coinsproject/autoload_classmap.php

```
<?php
return array();
?>
```

In Coinsproject/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Coinsproject;

class Module
{
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
         ),
         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
         ),
     );
 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }
}

?>
```

In Coinsproject/config/module.config.php

```
<?php

return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Coinsproject\Controller\Coinsproject' => 'Coinsproject\Controller\CoinsprojectController',
     ),
 ),


 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/coinsproject[/][:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Coinsproject\Controller\Coinsproject',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

 'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'coinsproject' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
 );

?>
```

In Coinsproject/src/Coinsproject/Controller/CoinsprojectController.php

```
<?php

namespace Coinsproject\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 class CoinsprojectController extends AbstractActionController
{
 public function indexAction()
 {
return new ViewModel();
 }
}
?>
```

In Coinsproject/view/coinsproject/coinsproject/index.phtml

```
<html>
my name is swapnil.
</html>
```

And after that i call my module in root/config/application.config.php but when i run it its not working anything.Where i did my mistakes?

Comment: "its not working anything" is not enough to describe your problem. If you're seeing a white screen that means "look at the logs and find the actual error". If it's not behaving the way you expect you need to be specific

Comment: Sir i am seeing a white screen and i want to know description of these program what i am writing here and why it is showing me white screen??

Comment: A white screen always means that you haven't configured your error reporting correctly and are not ready to start developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Coinsproject/config/module.config.php

```
'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
```

to

```
'routes' => array(
         'coinsproject' => array(
```

you forget to change the route into coinsproject first, i don't know if it's the only correction to make, but it's a beginning.

Comment: Thanks sir,if you think this problem will be helpfull for someone please upvote this.

Answer (score 1):

may be you should put index.phtml in

```
Coinsproject/view/coinsproject/index.phtml 
[Modulename]/view/[Controllername]/[actionname].phtml
```

not in

```
Coinsproject/view/coinsproject/coinsproject/index.phtml
```

and try to correct define view script (phtml file) in module.config.php in view_manager

```
  'view_manager' => array(
       'template_map' => array(
            coinsproject/coinsproject/index => __DIR__ . '/../view/coinsproject/index.phtml
        )
    )
```